# Groovy/Grails slow at reading big csv file

Tags: php, csv, grails, groovy

I have a big csv file (168MB, 149K rows, 125 cols).
I want to get the sum of the third column with the following code:

```
def tot = 0

new File("/path/to/big/file.csv").splitEachLine(";") { row ->
    try {
        tot += row[2].toBigDecimal()
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}

println tot
```

and it takes 11 secs:

```
root@front1:~# time groovy test.groovy
8691797.09805144

real    0m10.965s
user    0m9.977s
sys     0m0.500s
root@front1:~#
```

I've a similar code written in php that takes only 2 seconds to get the same result on the same machine.

Is there any tuning or better code that I should do in groovy/grails in order to get the same execution time ?

Thanks

Groovy Version: 2.3.8 JVM: 1.6.0_29 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

Comment: obviously php is better :=-)

Comment: eheh good point, I tried implementing the same routine in ruby and I get an execution time of 10s (same as groovy/grails), while a golang compiled implementation takes 2 seconds as php, I don't get what's happening...

Comment: have you taken the startup time for groovy into consideration?

Comment: yes, using timeduration I get 8.6 seconds execution time. As far as I understand the split takes long time, the same scanning with simple eachLine is very fast

Comment: Is it quicker if you make `tot` a BigDecimal, then use `tokenize` on lines returned by `eachLine` rather than the regex split? And add `Double.valueOf(row[2])` instead of using toBigDecimal

Comment: it gets better, down to 6.9 seconds, but far from 2.5 seconds it takes php

Comment: Try `BigDecimal tot = 0; String line; file.withReader { r -> while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {tot += line.tokenize(';')[2]}}`

Comment: This seems like a great candidate for `@CompileStatic`

Comment: using file.withReader doesn't improve performances. As I see bootleneck is the split or tokenize functions, they're slow. I tried using indexOf and substring stopping after first 3 matches (getting third column) and with this approach execution time goes down to 2 secs...

Comment: Try to using grails csv plugin http://grails.org/plugin/csv maybe it'll more faster.

Comment: php's builtin function to split csv is written in C, so the 2s case for php and go is most likely as good as it gets.  +1 for not parsing the whole line but just the data needed.  is this result with `@CompileStatic`? i played around with it a little (using a StringTokenizer, which is lazy) with CompileStatic was fastest in my test https://gist.github.com/christoph-frick/070cb386d27176f6735a

Comment: @Luca Did you reduce the time by 2 seconds or the total time when down to 2 secs? If it's a total of 2 seconds are you happy with the performance now?

Comment: Hi, total time went down to 2 secs, but only when I make calculations on the third column and stop parsing the whole line. While php and go implementation get 2 secs execution time parsing the whole line. Actually this was just an excerpt but in production I need to make calculation on any set of columns and I need parsing the whole line, so the java implementation is just slow compared to php/go.